# Secure data storage in OWA

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We are developing end-to-end encryption for email messages with OWA and JavaScript. We are using asymmetric encryption so we need to keep private key with OWA on the device of user (or elsewhere where it is secure and private). 
Is that possible? If not, what other other options we have with OWA? I know we can do that with COM add-ins but we must do that with OWA in order to be cross platform. Thanks.

Comment: The chance that you will develop a secure e-to-e encryption system is close to zero, essentially there are only a couple of implementation that are secure. Also this is not the best place to ask such a question, this forum is about helping with problem code, you have no code.

Comment: Which is the right place?

Comment: [cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [information security](https://security.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

> We are using asymmetric encryption so we need to keep private key with OWA on the device of user (or elsewhere where it is secure and private). Is that possible?

There is no accessible from add-on secure enough storage to keep user's private key.

> If not, what other other options we have with OWA?

If you care about security of your solution and in particular user's credential,  the one option I can see is to retrieve the private key every time it needs to be used. This would require very well authenticated service which may deliver user's private key upon request. Authentication should be #1 concern in this solution to make sure you are releasing private key to the right hands.

Another option is to use built-in SMIME capability for OWA. In this solution you need to think how to store user's credential into accessible store (CAPI on Windows; keychain on Mac/iOS). More on this possible solution over there: [Encrypt messages by using S/MIME in Outlook Web App](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/encrypt-messages-by-using-s-mime-in-outlook-web-app-2e57e4bd-4cc2-4531-9a39-426e7c873e26)

And probably last, but the best one ... continue using COM add-in for end point encryption.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Users Roaming setting is a great place to store keys/tokens while building cross platform Web  Add-in ,Roaming settings APIs of  Office.js should be helpful in achieving the goal

Please refer to Office.js Roaming settings APIs for more details

Comment: As per [RoamingSettings](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/RoamingSettings?product=outlook&version=v1.5) Doc: "*settings should not be considered secure storage*", as of they should not be used to store sensitive information such as user credentials or security tokens.